# Update of raspbian downloaded to Ubuntu

Tags: raspbian

How to download a rasbian update to a Ubuntu computer and then push it out to raspberry pis that have no internet access and never will have Internet access.

Comment: You can download the files put them on a USB flash drive and run dpkg. It may  be easier to download the entire package repo to make handling dependencies easier http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline. Curious, how are you going to handle time or don't you care about it.

Comment: Could you please explains how to do this in a bit more detail for the raspberry Pi and Ubuntu rather than just linking to another question that doesn't tell me much about what I want to know.

Comment: OK, what is the actual use case here, if they are never connected to a network why do they need to be updated. The won't have network security issues only physical (SD Card), and assuming they are running OK bug fixes are not an issue.